# Jquery addition and multiplication calculation

Tags: jquery, calculation

I'm calculating some Jquery variables, but don't know why else if condition is not getting true please check with below code

```
function roomCalc(){
  var noOfAdults = 2; // this is dynamic //parseInt($('#adults').val());
  var noOfChilds = 0;// this is dynamic parseInt($('#childs').val());
  var noofXtraAdults = 15000;//parseInt($('#extraAdult').val());
  var noofXtraChilds = 15000;//parseInt($('#extraChild').val());
  var maxRoomToatal = 1000;//parseInt($('#maxRoomToatal').text());

  $('#adults').keyup(function(){
    if(noOfAdults <= 2 )
  {
      var totalOutput = maxRoomToatal;
  }
  else if(noOfAdults >= 3 ){
    var totalOutput = noofXtraAdults + maxRoomToatal;
  }

  alert(totalOutput); 
});

}
roomCalc();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not assigned your input value to noOfAdults.

```js
function roomCalc() {
  var noOfAdults = 2; // this is dynamic //parseInt($('#adults').val());
  var noOfChilds = 0; // this is dynamic parseInt($('#childs').val());
  var noofXtraAdults = 15000; //parseInt($('#extraAdult').val());
  var noofXtraChilds = 15000; //parseInt($('#extraChild').val());
  var maxRoomToatal = 1000; //parseInt($('#maxRoomToatal').text());

  $('#adults').keyup(function() {
    noOfAdults = $('#adults').val() > 0 ? $('#adults').val() : noOfAdults;
    if (noOfAdults <= 2) {
      var totalOutput = maxRoomToatal;
    } else if (noOfAdults >= 3) {
      var totalOutput = noofXtraAdults + maxRoomToatal;
    }

    $("#maxRoomToatal").html(totalOutput);

  });

}
roomCalc();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="adults" type='number'>
<div id="maxRoomToatal"></div>
```

Comment: you need to do that also for other variable as per your requirement

Comment: can you please explain why you have added this line noOfAdults =  $('#adults').val()>0? $('#adults').val():noOfAdults;

Comment: as you mentioned in question `noOfAdults` is dynamic so need to set the input value to this variable, this statement simple do that task if the value of input is greater that 0 then it ll assign that else default value 2 will set

Comment: okay. 
also 1 more query currently output is coming in the alert box. how to show output on id?

Comment: you mean to html element

Comment: Yes Please last query

Comment: for input use `$(selector).val(totalOutput)` for other element use `.html()` or `.text()`

Comment: i tried above not working $('#maxRoomToatal').html(totalOutput);

Comment: for which element is this div or label or span

Comment: <div id="maxRoomToatal"></div>

Comment: <div id="maxRoomToatal"> <?php echo $single_row['col_hb_room_price'];?></div> we are calculating  var maxRoomToatal and displaying output to same id ... is this right way ?

Comment: may be your input type is text change that to number

Comment: might be no issues I will try. Thank you @Omi for your great and quick support really appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148554/discussion-between-harshad-patil-and-omi).